# How can I get the absolute path to the Eclipse install directory?

Tags: eclipse-plugin, directory, installation

I am writing an Eclipse product, composed of plugins.
In one of my plugins, I need to get the absolute path to the directory where Eclipse is installed.
(i.e. `/Applications/Eclipse` on Mac or `C:\Program Files\Eclipse` on Win).

Can't find an API for this. Ideas?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[codejammer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/426329/codejammer) suggests:

> The following gives you the installed location

```
Platform.getInstallLocation().getURL()
```

See the [`org.eclipse.core.runtime.Platform` API](http://kickjava.com/src/org/eclipse/core/runtime/Platform.java.htm#1314)

```
/**
 * Returns the location of the base installation for the running platform
 * <code>null</code> is returned if the platform is running without a configuration location.
 * <p>
 * This method is equivalent to acquiring the <code>org.eclipse.osgi.service.datalocation.Location</code>
 * service with the property "type" equal to {@link Location#INSTALL_FILTER}.
 *</p>
 * @return the location of the platform's installation area or <code>null</code> if none
 * @since 3.0
 * @see Location#INSTALL_FILTER
 */
```

Comment: getInstanceLocation seemed to provide the current eclipse workspace, strangely enough. however Platform.getInstallLocation().getURL() provided exactly what I needed, which I found by exploring the rest of the Platform methods. Thanks!

Comment: The first part of above answer should be removed. 'Instance location' is just another name for 'workspace', and that's not what was asked for. Second part is the correct answer.

Answer (score 5):

It should be

```
Platform.getInstallLocation().getURL()
```