# Plugin Development, where to save user data?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am developing a plugin for Eclipse. When the user runs the application for the first time, calibration takes place. This is where user data is taken and then printed out to text files, so that when used again, the system will remember their settings.

I was wondering where is the best place to store these text files on a user's system?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are different options with different scopes:

- per installation: see [the post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4494528/how-can-i-get-the-absolute-path-to-the-eclipse-install-directory), create a unique folder under the mentioned path and store the files there
- per user: create a unique folder under the users home directory (`System.getProperty("user.dir")`) and store the files there
- per workspace: `Plugin::getStateLocation` returns a path that is unique to the given plug-in for each workspace. Store your files there. `Plugin` is an abstract class that is implemented by the *Activator* or your plug-in. If you don't have such class yet, create it by specifying the Activator in the manifest editor. Alternatively you can use `Platform::getStateLocation()` if you have a reference to the Bundle that represents your plug-in.

Answer (score 1):

A common place to store such data is the

> AppData\Local\YourPluginName

directory.

You may also use the

> eclipse/plugins/YourPlugin

directory.

Answer (score 1):

Your plugin can store data in the workspace metadata in the plugin 'state location'

Use something like:

```
Bundle bundle = FrameworkUtil.getBundle(getClass());

IPath stateLoc = Platform.getStateLocation(bundle);
```

`stateLoc` will be a directory where your plugin can store whatever it likes. The location will normally be '.metadata/.plugins/your plugin id' in the workspace.